# Unable to Catch the Error using the below code using Protractor API

Tags: javascript, protractor

I've created a function in which I'm knowingly passing incorrect locator such that I would like to catch the error.. below is the code..

```
SafeClick:function(locator){
    try {
       _elementIdentify = locator.isDisplayed().then(function(){
          console.info('Element Displayed');
          locator.click();
       }, function(err) {
          console.error('Error Finding the Element', +err );
       });
    } catch(err) {
       console.info('Error occured');
    }
}
```

But with the above code, the statement in the catch block is not printed.

Comment: how do you throwing error? first run this code without try catch block and see if it is throwing error in console.

Comment: Without using Try Catch Block and passing an incorrect locator, I can see 'NoSuchElement Exception' in the console

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you try to catch error from a callback. You can not do that. Stuff in callback function is executed in different context so you will never catch that one from inside the then callback, even if you throw somewhere there.

EDIT: to catch the error you can try to write it like that:

```
SafeClick:function(locator){

       _elementIdentify = locator.isDisplayed().then(function(){
        try {
          console.info('Element Displayed');
          locator.click();
        }
        catch(err) {
          console.info('Error occured');
        }
       }, function(err) {
          console.error('Error Finding the Element', +err );
       });
}
```

This is the only way to catch an exception from a callback.
As a side note, that thing you try to write seems unnecessary. You should know the state of the UI you manipulate with protractor. If it is in wrong state, you want it to fail right?

Comment: Thanks for the details. But would like to know more if I can catch an error from a function which returns promise. In the above code isDisplayed() is returning a promise

Comment: "If it is in wrong state, you want it to fail right?" - Absolutely. correct.

Comment: I've tried the above code provided by you, but still I'm unable to sort out my issue

Comment: That is probably because the promise throwing your exception ('NoSuchElement Exception')is higher up the stack of promises. That means that when isDisplayed() runs it returns a promise, that throws some time later this exception. You can not catch it. We attach a then for its returned promise, but it will be executed after the original code (promise callback) is run. There is no way that i know of to catch that. That code will catch exceptions thrown in your own callback though.